# MySQL query to return non-emty meta values from a Wordpress meta table

Tags: mysql

I would like to query all meta values of meta keys matching with a string, example of these are genre_metalmusic, genre_popmusic,genre_grunge,etc. It can be matched with:

```
%genre%
```

And I don't like to retrieve duplicated meta values. The problem is that some of these meta keys does not also have a value (empty). I would like to return only meta values that are not empty , not duplicated and matching with my string.

I have this query almost working for me, except that it won't filter the empty values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value  FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%genre%'
```

I have tried an additional condition to filter the NULL but it is not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value  FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%genre%' AND meta_value IS NOT NULL
```

Do you have some tips on how to effectively get the non-empty meta values from Wordpress meta table? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch, but have you tried this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value  
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%genre%' 
      AND meta_value IS NOT NULL
      AND meta_value <> ''
```